# PHP5 Requested URL not Found

Tags: php, apache, pdo

I'm trying to working on a already created website project. This website is currently Running on Ubuntu with Apache2 and PHP5.

I've installed the project on APACHE2. But when I'm going to the website I'm having this message :

> The requested URL /connexion/ was not found on this server.
>
> Apache/2.4.34 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80

I don't know what to do, bcause when on the terminal I'm writing :

> sudo tail -100 /var/log/apache2/error.log

I'm Having a PDO error :

```
    [Thu Nov 22 09:17:30.492444 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 2033] AH00163: Apache/2.4.34 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations

[Thu Nov 22 09:17:30.492509 2018] [core:notice] [pid 2033] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'

[Thu Nov 22 09:48:49.461147 2018] [php7:warn] [pid 2070] [client ::1:51398] PHP Warning:  Declaration of Client::create(PDO $bdd, $nom, $prenom, $email, $password, $telephone, $fax, $is_active, $site_id) should be compatible with Utilisateur::create(PDO $bdd, $nom, $prenom, $email, $password, $telephone, $fax, $is_active) in /var/www/html/{websitename}/model/Classes/Client.php on line 0, referer: http://localhost/

[Thu Nov 22 09:48:49.461201 2018] [php7:warn] [pid 2070] [client ::1:51398] PHP Warning:  Declaration of Client::update(PDO $bdd, $utilisateur_id, $nom, $prenom, $email, $password, $telephone, $fax, $is_active, $client_id, $site_id) should be compatible with Utilisateur::update(PDO $bdd, $id, $nom, $prenom, $email, $password, $telephone, $fax, $is_active) in /var/www/html/{websitename}/model/Classes/Client.php on line 0, referer: http://localhost/

[Thu Nov 22 09:48:49.461218 2018] [php7:warn] [pid 2070] [client ::1:51398] PHP Warning:  Declaration of Client::updateWithoutPassword(PDO $bdd, $utilisateur_id, $nom, $prenom, $email, $telephone, $fax, $is_active, $client_id, $site_id) should be compatible with Utilisateur::updateWithoutPassword(PDO $bdd, $id, $nom, $prenom, $email, $telephone, $fax, $is_active) in /var/www/html/{websitedown}/model/Classes/Client.php on line 0, referer: http://localhost/

[Thu Nov 22 09:48:49.463732 2018] [php7:warn] [pid 2070] [client ::1:51398] PHP Warning:  Declaration of Employee::create(PDO $bdd, $nom, $prenom, $email, $password, $telephone, $fax, $is_active, $role_id, $agence_id) should be compatible with Utilisateur::create(PDO $bdd, $nom, $prenom, $email, $password, $telephone, $fax, $is_active) in /var/www/html/{websitedown}/model/Classes/Employee.php on line 0, referer: http://localhost/

[Thu Nov 22 09:48:49.463792 2018] [php7:warn] [pid 2070] [client ::1:51398] PHP Warning:  Declaration of Employee::update(PDO $bdd, $utilisateur_id, $employe_id, $nom, $prenom, $email, $password, $telephone, $fax, $is_active, $role_id, $agence_id) should be compatible with Utilisateur::update(PDO $bdd, $id, $nom, $prenom, $email, $password, $telephone, $fax, $is_active) in /var/www/html/{websitedown}/model/Classes/Employee.php on line 0, referer: http://localhost/

[Thu Nov 22 09:48:49.463817 2018] [php7:warn] [pid 2070] [client ::1:51398] PHP Warning:  Declaration of Employee::updateWithoutPassword(PDO $bdd, $utilisateur_id, $employe_id, $nom, $prenom, $email, $telephone, $fax, $is_active, $role_id, $agence_id) should be compatible with Utilisateur::updateWithoutPassword(PDO $bdd, $id, $nom, $prenom, $email, $telephone, $fax, $is_active) in /var/www/html/{websitedown}/model/Classes/Employee.php on line 0, referer: http://localhost/
```

SO I've enabled PHP PDO in PHP ini, trying to install PHP. THe website is still not working... What can I do ?

(I've met the problem on Windows, changing PHP making the website working but not Ubuntu)

Comment: _“What can I do ?”_ - research what the error message means, if that is unclear to you …?

Comment: Well i don't understand the error, is due to PDO ?is already enable in PHP.ini.
This is not from the code this is working on Wamp.

Comment: _“The requested URL /connexion/ was not found on this server”_ - using this kind of URL probably means that some URL rewriting is involved. Have you checked where this is configured, and whether the necessary Apache module(s) are present, and that you are allowed to make the necessary configuration?

Comment: _“Well i don't understand the error”_ - well that’s why I asked you whether you have made an actual effort to _research_ it.

Comment: On my .htaccess I set this URL. So this is coming from my .htaccess. i've already  enabled Apache rewrite.

Comment: And, is your Apache configured to _use_ .htaccess files for per-directory configuration? Do you have the necessary “permission” to use the directives in question inside .htaccess (referring to AlllowOverride here)?

Comment: Yes the htaccess have the permission.
I really don't understand, it works great on Windows with Wamp but the website is not running at all on my Ubuntu with Apahe...

Comment: So what are you rewriting this to? Does it work when you call that second URL directly in your browser, instead of the “readable” version?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869092/how-to-enable-mod-rewrite-for-apache-2-2 Most likely, mod_rewrite is not active or the AllowOverride all option is not set so your .htaccess rules can't be used.

Comment: Si I've made a test, I've tried to disabled PHP, i can see my code once PHP is enble, lochalhost show me an error 500 and this is stil the same error in my logs...
Mod rewrite is already available.. I'm out of idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, so After severals trial, I fix it... Simply by doing this :

> systemctl status mysql

My website can now run normally.

THank you all for you

Answer (score 0):

I think, check your document path

> DocumentRoot: The directory out of which you will serve your documents.

In apache similar to apache configration in file  `httpd.conf` check `DocumentRoot=Your\document\path` and
 `<Directory Your\document\path>`

```
    <Directory Your\document\path>
# Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
# or any combination of:
#   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
#
# Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
# doesn't give it to you.
#
# The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
# http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
# for more information.
#
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI

#
# AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
# It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
#   AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
#
AllowOverride All

#
# Controls who can get stuff from this server.
#
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

and also you compare ubuntu apache and php configuration with Window apache and php configuration

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21487775)

Comment: Thank you for clarification